# Template language for natural language text mutations

Tags: nlp, semantics

Stuck upon a rather trivial task that seems to lead to a wider problem.

Need to be able to generate light variations of a same short text. Some word forms depend on the speaker's gender, some can be replaced with synonyms.

Pseudo code:

```
I {random:decided|made up my mind} to {random:try|test|give a try to}
this {new|fresh} {cool|awesome} {service|web service|online tool}.
```

I'm looking for an "industry standard" templating language to describe such texts and possible variations. Thinking further, I might want *global* variables (like the gender one), *cross-links* for dependencies picked earlier in the sentence.

This looks close to regular expressions syntax. Ideally it would be more readable/writable by non-programmers.

Perhaps the problem is well-known, with a solid state solution like some programming language specifically for the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find something like this so I set out to create it. The result is called [Nalgene - the natural language generation language](https://github.com/spro/nalgene). The syntax is fairly simple but also powerful enough to support recursive phrases, synonyms, captured values, and dependencies.

```
%
    $person.name went to the $place to %action

%action
    ~buy a new $item
    ~sell @posessive($person.gender) $item

~buy
    buy
    purchase

$place
    store
    market

...
```

It outputs generated sentences alongside a tree representation (the primary purpose is to generate training data for ML systems).

```
> jill went to the store to return her toothbrush

( %
    ( $person.name
        jill )
    ( $place
        store )
    ( %action
        ( $item
            toothbrush ) ) )
```

If you are still looking a year later, stop by and open an issue, and let me know what you seek in a dream NLG language.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you won't allow the brackets or separators to be used in the text (or somehow escape them), you can accomplish this without too much headache, for example in JavaScript:

```
function randreplace (txt) {
    var matches = txt.match(/\{([^}]+)\}/g);
    for (var m in matches) {
        m = matches[m];
        var opts = m.substring(1, m.length-1); // rm '{' and '}'
        opts = opts.split('|');
        var rand = opts[Math.floor(Math.random() * opts.length)];
        txt = txt.replace(m, rand);
    }
    return txt;
}
var example = "I {decided|made up my mind} to {try|test|give a try to} this {new|fresh} {cool|awesome} {service|web service|online tool}.";

console.log(randreplace(example));
```